# Trying to merge the duplicate dates columns to be unique so that it matches with all the columns using Pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

[image: OUTPUT EXCEL]

This is the output converted to excel using Pandas. Although the dates are same, I am getting it in different columns as they are coming from different JSONs and the columns associated to that date shift right. Possible to only get unique dates as header and append the values associated with it below?

Below is the JSON

```
[
    {'availability': 1, 'date': '2021-08-04'}, 
    {'availability': 1, 'date': '2021-08-03'}, 
    {'availability': 0.999421296, 'date': '2021-08-02'}, 
    {'availability': 1, 'date': '2021-08-01'}, 
    {'temp': 29.418599537000002, 'date': '2021-08-04'}, 
    {'temp': 29.398615741, 'date': '2021-08-03'}, 
    {'temp': 29.272759258999997, 'date': '2021-08-02'}, 
    {'temp': 29.390018505999997, 'date': '2021-08-01'}
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that pandas counts each item in your list as a record. you can solve this issue by this code:

```
dta = pd.json_normalize(dta)
dta = dta.groupby('date').first().reset_index()
```

output:

```
|    | date       |   availability |    temp |
|---:|:-----------|---------------:|--------:|
|  0 | 2021-08-01 |       1        | 29.39   |
|  1 | 2021-08-02 |       0.999421 | 29.2728 |
|  2 | 2021-08-03 |       1        | 29.3986 |
|  3 | 2021-08-04 |       1        | 29.4186 |
```